# What is the hadith forbidding bay' al-kali bil-kali?

Tags: source-identification, debt, bay-al-dayn

I was reading a (poorly written) essay recently, wherein a hadith was mentioned but not fully quoted.  Allegedly, the classical *fuqaha* used it to forbid *bay' al-kali bil-kali* (Selling of debts for debts).

Beyond that, all I know is that it was reported by Ibn 'Umar, as related by al-Tabrani (*sic*).

What does this hadith say, and how authentic is it?

Comment: It may be the hadith that forbids selling what you don't own.

Comment: @ashes999 I don't think so; that hadith is explicitly referenced later in the essay through al-Tirmidhi.

Comment: a link to the essay would be awesome.

Answer (score 3):

> عن ابن عمر - رضي الله عنهما - ، أن النبي صلى الله عليه وآله وسلم نهى
> عن بيع الكالئ بالكالئ
>
> The Prophet prohibited the selling of debts for debts

[The Hadith](https://sunnah.com/bulugh/7/80)

**Note:** One of the persons mentioned in the sanad of this Hadith is  (موسى بن عقبة) and that is a mistake, for the narrator actually is (موسى بن عبيدة).

As for the authenticity of the Hadith, it is Da'eef.

Sources: Irwa' Al Ghaleel  إرواء الغليل Chapter 5 Hadith 1382